# Adding a "preprocessor include" doesn't seem to have effect

Tags: ide, include, eclipse-cdt

I want the Ecplise CDT parser to pre-include a file not specified in my source file, for reasons I won't go into, so as not to complain about undeclared identifiers in various places.

I tried to do this using `Project | Properties | C/C++ General | Preprocesor Includes | Entries` and adding the relevant file for all languages. However, this doesn't seem to have an effect. If I go to `Paths and Symbols | Includes`, I can only add include directories, not include files.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the C/C++ parser to include my file?

**Note**: I'm using nVIDIA CUDA 8.0's nsight, a modified CUDA-enabled Eclipse; the platform version is 4.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, `Paths and Symbols | Includes` only supports include directories, so `Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.` is the way to go.

Some common pitfalls that you may be running into:

- In the `Entries` tab, are you selecting the correct language under `Languages`? Each language has its own set of entries.
- In the `Providers` tab, for `CDT User Setting Entries` (assuming that's the one you're adding the entries to), is `Use global provider shared between projects` unchecked? If it's checked, project-specific entries will be ignored.
- Have you rebuilt the project's index (`Project -> C/C++ Index -> Rebuild`)? New settings are typically not picked up until a rebuild of the index.

Other things that may help:

- If, in the `Add Include` dialog you are specifying the include file as a `Project Path` or `Workspace Path`, try using a `Filesystem Path` instead, even if the file is inside your project or workspace. This sometimes helps.
- In the same dialog, try checking `Treat as built-in`. I'm not sure what exactly this does for Include Files, but it has helped me in the past for Include Directories.

Finally, if none of this works, there is a more direct way to specify `-include` or any other flag:

- In the `Providers` tab, select the `Built-in Compiler Settings` provider.
- Be sure `Use global provider shared between projects` is unchecked
- Append `-include <path>` or whatever other flag to the `Command to get compiler specs`.